# Upper bound of series related to injective holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to figure out the following problem:

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an injective, analytic function whose Laurent series has the form
> $$
>  f(z)=z+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_kz^k.$$
> Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n|a_{-k}|^2\leq1$.

I have tried looking at problems such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88989/upper-bound-for-series-related-to-an-injective-holomorphic-function-on-the-unit) but am still unsure how to proceed. Any help or hints on this problem would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the Laurent expansion of $f(\frac{1}{z})$ around the origin?

Comment: @halbaroth Thanks, I computed $f(1/z)=1/z+\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}a_kz^{-k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{-k}z^k$; however I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any other tips?

Comment: You should get $f(\frac{1}{z}) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{-k} z^k$. This Laurent series is the same as the series in the post you have cited. Notice there is a mistake in this post, as it has been noticed by a contributor in the comments.